# How to "override" extension methods in .NET?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, extension-methods

So I have an object hierarchy to produce ui controls in asp.net mvc and try to achive a fluent api. I make some dummy class to focus on the current problem.
So here is the "wrong" codebase:

```
public abstract class HtmlElement { /* ... */ }

public abstract class UIElement : HtmlElement { /* ... */ }

public abstract class ButtonBase : UIElement { /* ... */ }

public class LinkButton : ButtonBase { /* ... */ }

public class ActionButton : ButtonBase { /* ... */ }


public static class HtmlElementExtensions
{
  public static T Id<T>(this T item, string id) where T : HtmlElement
  {
    /* set the id */
    return item;
  }
}

public static class ButtonBaseExtensions
{
  public static T Id<T>(this T item, string id) where T : ButtonBase
  {
    /* set the id and do some button specific stuff*/
    return item;
  }
}
```

When I try to call the Id on a LinkButton the compiler says there is ambiguous call:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton().Id("asd");
```

I really thought that the compiler choose the closest match in this case so if I have a Script class that inherits from HtmlElement than HtmlExtensions Id method called, and for a LinkButton (because of the restrictions) the ButtonBase method will be called.
I have a solution, but I'm not sure there is a better one.
I delete the Id method from ButtonBaseExtensions and modified the HtmlElementExtensions Id method as the following manner:

```
public static T Id<T>(this T item, string id) where T : HtmlElement
{
  if (item is ButtonBase)
  {
    /* do some button specific stuff*/
  }
  /* set the id */
  return item;
}
```

This way every class descendant from the ButtonBase is working.
I not really like my solution because it mix the HtmlElement logic with the ButtonBase logic.
Any idea/suggestion for a better solution?
I thought I put them in different namespace, but just for a second. I should have to use both namespace, so don't solve the problem.

Do you think it's worth to mention on the msdn forums as an idea that the compiler should watch the restrictions on generic extension methods?

In the meantime I make some more research and start a thread on msdn forums: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/c9ad51c1-0c5a-4eb6-a530-89eaa628c07f)
I tried some non-generic extension methodds:

```
  public class BaseClass { /*...*/ }
  public class InheritedClass : BaseClass { /*...*/ }

  public static class BaseClassExtensions
  {
    public static void SomeMethod(this BaseClass item, string someParameter)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BaseClassExtensions.SomeMethod called wtih parameter: {0}", someParameter));
    }
  }

  public static class InheritedClassExtensions
  {
    public static void SomeMethod(this InheritedClass item, string someParameter)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("InheritedClassExtensions.SomeMethod called wtih parameter: {0}", someParameter));
    }
  }
```

And  if I instantiate these:

```
BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
InheritedClass ic = new InheritedClass();
BaseClass ic_as_bc = new InheritedClass();

bc.SomeMethod("bc");
ic.SomeMethod("ic");
ic_as_bc.SomeMethod("ic_as_bc");
```

Produced this output:

```
BaseClassExtensions.SomeMethod called wtih parameter: bc
InheritedClassExtensions.SomeMethod called wtih parameter: ic
BaseClassExtensions.SomeMethod called wtih parameter: ic_as_bc
```

[You can vote it for now](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3886276-generic-extension-method-type-restriction-should-b)

Thanks,
Péter

Comment: An extension method is **not** a substitute for a virtual method, nor can it be made virtual.  It is quite unclear why you need one, given that you declared these classes yourself.  Just add a virtual method to one of the base classes and override it, where necessary, in a derived class.

Comment: Because of the fluent api I have to use extension methods. The generics inheritance only works with 2 level inheritence.
I wrote an example with the non-genric extension method where the compiler use the parameter restriction to determine the right method to call. I just wish that the compiler also evaluate generic parameter restrictions. I can't write "public static ButtonBase Id(this ButtonBase item, string id)" instead of "public static T Id<T>(this T item, string id) where T : ButtonBase" because the return type would be ButtonBase and it break the method chain of the fluent api.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look on the MSDN documentation about extension methods: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). The interesting part is under *Binding Extension Methods at Compile Time*:

> ... it first looks for a match in the type's instance methods. If no match is found, it will search for any extension methods that are defined for the type, and bind to the **first extension method that it finds**.

So this is why you see this behavior. And I actually can buy it, just imagine that somebody can overwrite how your application works with just one method `public static T Id<T>(this T item, string id) where T : object`. And if you will not see any compiler errors, you will think that everything is correct, and maybe everything will work, except some rarely cases. How confusing it could be?

And one more bad thing about your approach. If I will consume your API and will see that for Button I have two methods: one in `HtmlElementExtensions` and one in `ButtonBaseExtensions` what will stop me of doing this `HtmlElementExtensions.Id(button, "id")` instead of `ButtonExtensions.Id(button, "id")`?

In your case I'd prefer combined approach:

```
public static T Id<T>(this T item, string id) where T : HtmlElement
{
  if (item is ButtonBase)
  {
      return (T)Id((ButtonBase)item);
  } 
  else if (item is HtmlElement)
  {
      return (T)Id((HtmlElement)item);
  }

  throw new NotSupportedException("Type " + item.GetType() + " is not supported by Id extension method");
}

private static ButtonBase Id(ButtonBase item, string id)
{
     return item;
}

private static HtmlElement Id(HtmlElement item, string id)
{
     return item;
}
```

Comment: With my example the user can't overwrite my methods, because in the inheritance tree the the ButtonBase is much closer to LinkButton than the object. And you assume really malicious user. I think it's much simpler to add throw new Exception(); to the code to make errors. :D
Your answer is look alike my solution, just your a bit more elegant :)

Comment: @Péter yep, sorry. I was thinking about different direction. In case if you will have a `ButtonBase` and somebody will write extension method for `LinkButton`. And yes by 'combined approach' I meant both your solutions at once ;)